# Anisotropic LEDs: which direction has the wide cone?

Tags: led

I need to have a small board with anisotropic LEDs assembled and I am not sure how to orient the footprint. I am slightly confused by [this LED](https://datasheet.octopart.com/Q65110A1550-Osram-datasheet-13701590.pdf). OSRAM refers to the "wide" angle as "horizontal" throughout all their datasheets for anisotropc LEDs. However, the direction is never defined and whereever the LED is depicted the horizontal direction is the short axis. They also have the following nice graphic, but again, without ever defining the angle \$\varphi\$.

[image]

I found [another datasheet](https://datasheet.octopart.com/Q65110A1550-Osram-datasheet-13701590.pdf) which actually defines the "horizontal" direction:

[image]

I was under the impression that the long axis should always give the wider cone ? Unfortunately other datasheets, are also not really clear about this.

So which axis in an anisotropic flattop SMD LED gives the wide cone ? Or does this in fact vary between manufacturers?

Comment: The inset on the second diagram seems clear enough. Also, *"the long axis should always give the wider cone"* -- not sure why you would think this. It's a fundamental concept in optics that a larger aperture gives you a better ability to produce a more focused beam. BTW,  is the angle from the "boresight" axis -- i.e., straight out from the face of the LED.

Comment: @DaveTweed what you say about aparture only really holds for diffraction limited effects. Anyway. Let's try not to argue over this. Here is a similar datasheet which suddenly defines the "vertical" direction as the wide cone one: https://datasheet.octopart.com/LB-QH9G-N1OO-35-1-Osram-Opto-datasheet-142371163.pdf (again without defining what "vertical" means) So is OSRAM sloppy in one of the datasheets or does the wide cone direction vary from LED to LED?